# Prove that $N \setminus Z(G)\neq \langle e \rangle$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group with $\operatorname{ord}(G) = p^n$, where $p$ is a prime
number, and if $N \neq \langle e \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, prove that
$N \setminus Z(G)\neq \langle e \rangle$.

Comment: Also $Z(G)\neq <e>$ because $G$ is a $p$-group. Thus for $N=Z(G)$ the statement is false

Comment: If $H$ is a subgroup of any group $G$ and $e$ is the identity element, then $e \in H$, $e \in Z(G)$ and thus $ e\notin H \setminus Z(G)$. Therefore $H \setminus Z(G) \neq \langle e \rangle$. So the statement is always true. I think i'm missing something.

Comment: @Deiborlang Nongsiang You are absolutely right! I have deleted my comment that says the question is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might mean $N\cap Z(G) \neq \{e\}$. In which case,

1. Use the Class equation
2. If $x\in N$, then the conjugacy class $C(x) \subset N$

Comment: I don't know why this proposal of answer was downvoted: I also think the OP *actually* wanted to ask this as his question is trivially true for *any* group and subgroup, no matter whether finite, normal, etc.

Comment: I have upvoted Prahlad's answer again (it was -1 when I saw it), because I also suspect there is a \cap typo mismatch. Well done Prahlad!

Comment: Thanks guys. I was perplexed by the downvote too :)

Answer (score 0):

If $H$,$K$ are any subgroups of a group $G$, with identity $e$, then $H \setminus K \neq \langle e \rangle $, since $e \in H,K$ and hence $e \not\in H \setminus K $. Your question is a special case of that.

Comment: I am taking the question literally, rather than the likely meaning (which Prahlad answered)